# Disable F5 refresh in .Net Maui Blazor application

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

What will be proper way to disable refreshing of app by hitting F5 in .net7 windows targeted maui-blazor app.

With .net7.0 we are able to develop maui-blazor application targeting windows platform.

Visual studio nicely pack app which looks like native windows app, only issues so far is that windows app refresh itself on F5 key, from browser native functionality there is also search on F3 but that is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the JS function to disable the F5 refresh. Just add the following code into the /wwwroot/css/index.html:

```
  <script>
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to set AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled to false in Loaded event of MainPage.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        
    }
    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        #if WINDOWS
            var webView2 = (blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2);
            await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
       #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, and if you need the `ctrl-shift-i` shortcut to open the developer tools, you can put it into a `#if (WINDOWS && !DEBUG) ... #endif` block.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

#if WINDOWS
        var webView2 = (blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2);
        await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

        var settings = webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings;
        settings.IsZoomControlEnabled = false;
        settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
#endif
    }
}
```

and set Name on BlazorWebView in MainPage.xaml

```
<BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

Comment: Can't get this working in .net 8. F5 still refreshes the page and on the canonical counter page, resets the state to 0 after an F5 (like in the browser).